# Transitive reference in a NuGet package

Tags: dll, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet Package: **My.Framework**
This package has a method **MyMethod** Using [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)
My Package is used in another project **MyProject** calling **MyMethod**

Prism <-- **My.Framework** (**MyMethod**) <-- **MyProject**

My problem is when I execute **MyProject** it fails because the Prism.Dll is not present in the build folder.

Do you know how I can instruct MsBuild to Copy the Prism.Dll in the build folder?
Ideally, I would have the information defined in **My.Framework** package.

**Update**

MyFramework Package reference *correctly* Prism:
[image: NuGet references]

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your package's dependencies are defined in its [nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element)